# Regex match based on prefix and suffix

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python 3 and `re` module.

Here are the strings:

```
s1 = "http://52portal/flood-2011-year-39090/gallery?p=3"
s2 = "http://52portal/flood-2011-year-39090"
```

I need to get `39090` number, ids are always given so that number has a prefix `-` and no particular suffix.

I have an implementation when no other numbers are in url:

```
pattern = r'-([0-9]+)'
re.findall(pattern, s)[0]
```

How would I tell the program to ignore the number that has suffix and prefix `-`?

Comment: [`(?<=-)\d+(?=/|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/tX9xC1/1)? You need to find the right-side boundary. It can be `/` or end of string.

Comment: @stribizhev this works, offer it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the right-side boundary. It can be `/` or end of string.

```
(?<=-)\d+(?=/|$)
```

Here, `(?<=-)` is a positive look-behind that checks if there is a hyphen before 1 or more digits (`\d+`) and `(?=/|$)` is a positive look-ahead that makes sure there is `/` or end of string right after that sequence.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tX9xC1/1)

Here is [sample code](http://ideone.com/XGb8HM):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<=-)\d+(?=/|$)')
test_str = "http://52portal/flood-2011-year-39090/gallery?p=3\nhttp://52portal/flood-2011-year-39090"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as

```
(?<=-)[0-9]+?(?=/|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/sY3qI2/2